# Вывод кода внутри PHP кода

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть табличка, которая выводится в цикле

```
do { printf ("<table><tr><td>%s</td></tr></table>", $myrow["a"]); }
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Как сделать, чтобы сначала выводился код `<table>` ,потом цикл, потом `</table>`?

p.s. Сами строчки выводятся спокойно. Загвоздка только с выводом тегов таблицы, до и после конструкции do while. Пробовал стандартно, через echo, ничего не получилось.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo '<table>';
do { echo "<tr><td>".$myrow["a"]."</td></tr>"; }
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
echo '</table>';
```

Не понимаю, что не получается.

**Добавлено**

```
$str = '<table>';
do { $str .= "<tr><td>".$myrow["a"]."</td></tr>"; }
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
$str. = '</table>';
echo $str;
```

Еще вариант.

Comment: разобрался... не работало из за одинарных ковычек в теге Table